# List files on web server on asp webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to list documents as links that sit on a web server on an asp webpage.

The folders on the server are structured as www.website.com\docs\manufacturer\model\ then the docs relating each model are on the relevant folder.

I have a list of items in a table which I can view as a complete list in the view\index.cshtml file. When I go to the view\details.cshtml I want to list the relevant documents for that item. Each item has the manufacturer and model information so I figured I can use this to build the url of the folder but not sure how to code the page to show all the documents in that folder.

Hope this makes some sense.

UPDATE

I have tried the following:

```
  @* Get the get model and manufacturer from Asset*@
    @{string modelname = Model.Equipment.ModelName;}
    @{string manufacturername = Model.Equipment.Manufacturer;}

    @* Calcualte path*@
    @{string baseFolder = string.Format("www.somewebiste.co.nz/docs/{0}/{1}/", manufacturername, modelname);}
    @* Enumerate the files *@
    @{IEnumerable<string> files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);}
```

However when I run it I get the following error:

An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\www.somewebiste.co.nz\docs\Mitsubishi Electric\MSZ-GA80VA'.

I can see the local path to IIS being prepended to the directory string however the files are on some website and not local.

Note I have not tried to code the output yet. Just working through line by line.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Hi, Apologies. I have not shown what I have tried as I am not sure where to start with the particular problem described. I am new to asp.net and still trying to get my head around how it all works. I have looked for tutorials on this but could not find one that covered what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// Get the model from the user - perhaps via query string?
string model = Request.QueryString["Model"];
// Calcualte your path
string baseFolder = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/docs/manufacturer/model/{0}", model);
// Enumerate the files; perhaps *.* is too broad? *.pdf better?
IEnumerable<string> files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string path in files) 
{
  // write out whatever portion of path you want here
}
```

The trick to making this work, however, is ensuring your IIS account has permissions to enumerate (read) the subject folder/files.

IIS 6 typically uses a standard Windows account called 'Network Service' to execute ASP.NET code. This implies that if you want to interact with the file system, the Network Service account needs read permissions to the subject files.

IIS 7.5 and later gets a bit trickier, though more secure. By default, each Application Pool executes under a virtual account (e.g. 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'). Just like with Network Service, you will need to explicitly grant permissions to this account to interact with the file system. However, the subject account is not listed under the list of user accounts. (It's a, ahem, virtual account.) No matter, simply type the name into the Select Users or Groups permissions dialog, and Windows will accept the virtual account name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Please see update above as to progress. not quite working yet :-)

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Is the code you are writing running on www.somewebiste.co.nz, or is www.somewebiste.co.nz a remote website that your websites is attempting to list files from?

Comment: The somewebsite.co.nz a remote site. sorry should have pointed that out

Comment: Ah, then your solution is at least in part dependent on the remote website: do they support the listing of files?  E.g. if you invoke http://somewebsite.co.nz/docs/Mitsubishi Electric, do you get a list of file, or an HTTP error stating that directory listings are denied or resource not found?

If you get listing, then you can use HttpWebRequest to retrieve the HTML, parse it, and emit the files to your users.

Comment: Yes, you can see the files when you view the site in a browser. I'll give your suggestion a go.